# Why VS Code always try to generate a new jsconfig.json file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

There is a relatively large project which has typescript and javascript files mixed together. I've already generate a `tsconfig.json` and it works pretty well.

The problem is, everytime I use VS Code to open this project, the editor always try to generate a `jsconfig.json` for me, even I create a `jsconfig.json` manually, the editor still try to create a new one.

I also try with another project, of course a new and smaller one, no problem like above, this is very confusing, what's the cause behind the scene?

Comment: are you using any plugins like jslint/jshint etc..?

Comment: @SurajRao I'm using eslint plugin, but I don't think it causes the problem. FYI, I'm using VS Code insider version, I will try to use a stable version instead.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, this problem is caused by an extension called **ember-cli for vscode**, just disable it if you suffered a lot. Also, I've already file an issue, hope it gives us an option in the near future.

Comment: Tip: You can disable an extension per project or workspace, so that it's kept enabled for other projects.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was "Meteor" extension which was creating a new jsconfig.json file every time I open my react project in vs code.